# MySQL Query to get the first matched rows in the given list

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my Sample table

```
| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| ----- |------ |
| Val 1 | Dat 1 |
| Val 3 | Dat 2 |
| Val 1 | Dat 3 |
| Val 4 | Dat 4 |
| Val 1 | Dat 5 |
| Val 5 | Dat 6 |
| Val 5 | Dat 7 |
| Val 1 | Dat 8 |
| Val 6 | Dat 9 |
```

I want to extract values form this table based on the first matching value in an ordered list.

For example if the list is (`Val 10`, `Val 1`, `Val 5`, `Val 6`).  I want to get all the rows that have  `Col 1` as `Val 10`. If no rows matches, then return rows that have `Col 1` as `Val 1`. If nothing is found repeat the process with next value in the list.

So the expected result for the list (`Val 10`, `Val 1`, `Val 5`, `Val 6`) is:

```
| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| ----- |------ |
| Val 1 | Dat 1 |
| Val 1 | Dat 3 |
| Val 1 | Dat 5 |
| Val 1 | Dat 8 |
```

Example 2: The expected result for the list ( `Val 6`, `Val 10`, `Val 1`, `Val 5`) is:

```
| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| ----- |------ |
| Val 6 | Dat 9 |
```

I tried the following

```mysql
SELECT `Col 2` 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE `Col 1` IN ('Val 10', 'Val 1', 'Val 5', 'Val 6')
ORDER BY FIELD(`Col 1`, 'Val 10', 'Val 1', 'Val 5', 'Val 6')
```

But I am getting all the rows from the table that have matches in the list. I am resorting to `for` loop on the code side. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `DENSE_RANK()` here along with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE `Col 1` WHEN 10 THEN 1
                                                       WHEN 1  THEN 2
                                                       WHEN 5  THEN 3
                                                       WHEN 6  THEN 4 END) dr
    FROM table1
)

SELECT `Col 1`, `Col 2`
FROM cte
WHERE dr = 1;
```

The above logic ranks all `Col 1 = 10` records as 1st rank, `Col 1 = 1` records as 2nd rank.  It then retains only those records having the first rank.

Answer (score 1):

On 5.x you may use

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Val 10,Val 1,Val 5,Val 6', ',', MIN(NULLIF(FIND_IN_SET(`Col 1`, 'Val 10,Val 1,Val 5,Val 6'), 0))), ',', -1) AS `Col 1`
               FROM test ) t2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=794ce9ead93f6e47a013b4b5924a22e2

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit for get only 1 record from database.

> SELECT `Col 2`  FROM `table1`  WHERE `Col 1` IN ('Val 10', 'Val 1',
> 'Val 5', 'Val 6') ORDER BY FIELD(`Col 1`, 'Val 10', 'Val 1', 'Val 5',
> 'Val 6') Limit 1;